# variable doesn't update when trying to increment it while using useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a variable initialized in the following way:

```
let [count_farmers, set_count_farmers] = useState(0);
```

What I'm trying to do is, when a person is Registering to my page, I wish to increment the variable, like so:

```
let handleAddUser = (userinfo) => {
    console.log("before: " + count_farmers);
    set_count_farmers(count_farmers + 1);
    console.log("after: " + count_farmers);
    //check if email exists @ anyone of the users, if so, don't create!
    let found_user = usersVal.find((user) => userinfo.email == user.email);
    if (found_user === undefined && userinfo.email.includes("@")) {
      console.log(getFarmerImageByName(count_farmers % 5));
      usersEditVal([
        ...usersVal,
        {
          firstname: userinfo.firstname,
          lastname: userinfo.lastname,
          fullname: userinfo.firstname + " " + userinfo.lastname,
          reviews: [{ idReviewer: "", text: "" }],
          location: "Tel Aviv",
          likes: 0,
          about:
            "this is a default about textthis is a default about textthis is a default about textthis is a default aboefbout text",
          likedProfilesId: [],
          likedProductsId: [],
          img: getFarmerImageByName(count_farmers % 5),
          id: v4(),
          isFarmer: userinfo.isFarmer,
          password: userinfo.password,
          email: userinfo.email,
          farmerProducts: [],
          cartProducts: [],
          soldItems: [],
        },
      ]);

      return true;
    } else {
      console.log("EMAIL IS INVALID.");
      return false;
    }
    //****************************************************************** */
  };
```

Now, doesn't matter how many times I register, the console log of before and after (1st and 3rd lines in the function handleAddUser), I get 0 printed to the screen.

Any ideas?

Regards!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: I answered your question. On a side note, you are incrementing that state no matter if the registering process was successful or failed, is that what you want? Also, is all of that information coming from a form? If so, have you made sure to e.preventDefault() that form when submitted?

Comment: Thanks! and yes, I'm aware of that, at the moment i'm just attempting to make it increment without caring so much whether it succeeds or not. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, as you are using the previous value of the state to determine a new one, you'll need to use the useState function feature as your actual implementation is problematic.

You can use it like that:

```
set_count_farmers((previous) => previous + 1)
```

That way, our state is being updated with the previous value given by the state itself, and not what we assume it is at that given time. It is much more stable to do it that way, although doing it your way works, it will leads to issues.

Now, you need to know that useState is asynchronous, and that it will be done, but that your `console.log()` occurs too fast.

There is a simple way using `useEffect()` to log a value when it changes, as it is what you want.

Just use the `array dependency` of `useEffect()` to listen to any change made to `count_farmers`.

The code should looks like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log("A change has been detected in count_farmers: ", count_farmers)
}, [count_farmers])
```

This will log your count **AFTER** it has been updated, making sure you never log too early.

Also, you have to remember how a component life-cycle works, and that it gets re-rendered each time a state changes. So actually, you could also log it each time the page gets re-rendered ([] dependency), and it would also works. But, it is more appropriate to listen to that particular state to provide updates.